# perl one liners + print line if match last word but with space

Tags: bash, ksh, perl

The following perl  syntax will print the line in case line was ended with "DUPLEX"

But Sometimes DUPLEX have one space or more as

```
   "DUPLEX    "
```

so in this case line will not printed

Please advice what I need to add in my perl syntax in order to print the line that ended with the word - DUPLEX

in spite there are some spaces after the word "DUPLEX"

```
perl -ne "print if /DUPLEX$/" file
```

.

```
more file

VAL=18327 FULL DUPLEX
VAL=782      HALF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just look for 0 or more spaces:

```
perl -ne "print if /DUPLEX\s*$/" file
```

In the Perl regular expression language, `\s` matches any whitespace character and `*` means 0 or more.